# Download file to client PC and post back to page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, download, response

I have a web page which returns a set of results which you can then ask for in a .csv format.

As the creation of the file is quite lengthy (at times up to 30 minutes), I have added some JavaScript that adds a class to a div so that it covers the screen, to tell users that the report is being created and to be patient.

After the file has been created and downloaded I would like the div to then return to its original state of not being there (so to speak).

Here is what I currently have.

JavaScript

```
function skm_LockScreen() {
    var lock = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_skm_LockPane');
    var lock2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pleaseWait');
    if (lock)
        lock.className = 'LockOn';
    if (lock2)
        lock2.className = 'WaitingOn';
}
function skm_UnLockScreen() {
    var lock = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_skm_LockPane');
    var lock2 = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pleaseWait');
    if (lock)
        lock.className = 'LockOff';
    if (lock2)
        lock2.className = 'WaitingOff';
}
```

Button

```
<asp:Button ID="LatestReportButton" runat="server" CssClass="standardButton" Text="Latest Quote Report" Width="140px"
OnClick="ReportButton_Click" CommandArgument="2" OnClientClick="skm_LockScreen()" />
```

Code behind

```
protected void ReportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(base.GetType(), "unlock", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">skm_UnLockScreen();</script>");
        try
        {
            //Start creating the file
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempDest + "\\" + csvGuid + ".csv", true))
            {
                //Code to create the file goes 
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.csv");
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile("CreatedReport.csv");
        Response.End();
    }
```

The issue I'm having is that the JavaScript is never written back to the page because of the Response.End();

I've already done it as two buttons, one to create the report the other to download it, but my company would prefer it to be all in one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the length of time needed to generate the report, the method you're proposing contains a number of inherent risks, each of which will cause the report creation to fail:

- the user may accidentally close the browser / tab;
- the browser / tab might crash;
- timeouts may occur on the web server.

I would tackle this problem in a different way. In the first instance, I would look to see if the report generation can be optimized - "30 minutes" rings alarm bells immediately. Assuming database(s) are involved at some point, I would investigate the following as a minimum:

- Are database indexes being used, or used correctly?
- Do the report generation queries contain inefficient operations (CURSORs, for example)?
- Do the execution plans reveal any other flaws in the report generation process?

If this isn't a option (let's assume you can't modify the DBs for whatever reason), I would still consider a totally different approach to generating the report, whereby the report creation logic is moved outside of the web application into, say, a console app.

For this, you would need to define:

- a way to pass the report's parameters to the report generation app;
- a way to identify the user that requested the report (ideally login credentials, or Windows identity);
- a way to notify the user when the report is ready (email, on-screen message);
- a directory on the server where the reports will be saved and downloaded from;
- a separate page from which the user can download the report.

A couple of database tables should be sufficient to log this information.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I ended up creating the report in a new window which indicates to the user that the report is being created and to be patient. This window then downloaded the file when finished.